# How to discard midpoints or only get borders of polygon

Tags: javascript, geojson, geometry, java

I have a List of LatLng objects that I use to make a polygon to represent a road with a buffer, but sometimes exist returns as next image:
[image]

shared typescript implementation:

[image]

The points in this area overlap when creating a polygon, what strategy can I use to discard the midpoints?
I would like to achieve it using only Java or JavaScript.

Comment: Please share the code as text instead of screenshot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Union of polygons can be used to get only outside borders of overlapping polygons. In JS this can be done with `turf.union` function from [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library.

If we have the following collection of polygons:

```
var polygons = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              14.490189510012036,
              46.04599661038506
            ],
            [
              14.490359382464196,
              46.045797645591139
            ],
            [
              14.49494593273242,
              46.04728618163216
            ],
            [
              14.494712357507412,
              46.047529354589759
            ],
            [
              14.490189510012036,
              46.04599661038506
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": null
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              14.49041246730385,
              46.04594502682653
            ],
            [
              14.49057172219407,
              46.045709216506569
            ],
            [
              14.494924698351055,
              46.04711669686728
            ],
            [
              14.494669890229697,
              46.04736723957541
            ],
            [
              14.49041246730385,
              46.04594502682653
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": null
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              14.487917469073663,
              46.045237591558279
            ],
            [
              14.488129809360423,
              46.044861762774448
            ],
            [
              14.49114504158089,
              46.04581975271131
            ],
            [
              14.490837147877367,
              46.04616609858658
            ],
            [
              14.487917469073663,
              46.045237591558279
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
      "properties": null
    }
  ]
}
```

which looks like this (light blue):

[image]

then this code:

```
var polygonUnion = null;
turf.featureEach(polygons, function(feature) {
  if (!polygonUnion)
    polygonUnion = feature;
  else {
    polygonUnion = turf.union(polygonUnion, feature);
  }
});
```

will produce this polygon union (red):

[image]